# Node version v21.6.1 when connect with strapi then showing "Strapi requires Node.js >=18.0.0 <=20.x.x"

Tags: node.js, strapi

How to downgrade Node.js version from 21 to 20 using Node Version Manager (NVM)?

I am working on a project that requires Node.js version 20.x.x. However, my development environment is configured with Node.js version 21.6.1. I need to downgrade Node.js to version 20 using Node Version Manager (NVM) in my Visual Studio Code terminal.

Could someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish this task?

I'm looking for guidance on how to:

- Install Node Version Manager (NVM) if it's not already installed.
- Download and install Node.js version 20 using NVM.
- Set Node.js version 20 as the active version in my Visual Studio Code terminal.
- Verify that the installation was successful and I'm now using Node.js version 20.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

knowing nvm made my life actually better :). To install:

1. Follow this wonderful article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/. Get used to bash scripting, you will need it more than you think onwards.
2. If you can execute `nvm --version` on your terminal, then it is properly installed.
3. To install the node version you want, just execute `nvm install <<version>>`. So for node 20.1.5, you can execute `nvm install 20.1.5`.
4. Then execute `nvm use <<version>>` to use the node version.
5. To check the node version, execute `node --version`.